# If $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ exists then either $f\equiv0$ on $\Bbb C$ or $f(z)\not =0$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let , $f,g:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be analytic such that $g(z)\not =0,\forall z\in \mathbb C$. If $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ exists then  prove that either $f\equiv0$ on $\Bbb C$ or $f(z)\not =0$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$.

**My Attempt:**

If $f(z)\not = 0, \forall z\in \mathbb C$ then there is nothing to proof. So suppose that, $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0\in \mathbb C$. Let $z_0$ be a zero of $f$ of order $k$. Then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^kh(z)$ , where $h(z_0)\not =0$.

Now I want to show that $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$. But, how we use the condition ' $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ exists ' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g\neq0$ the function $h=f/g$ is entire. Since the limit $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}h$ exists, the function $h$ is constant. Therefore $f=hg\neq0$ or $h\equiv 0$.

---

If $\lim_{|z|\to0}h$ exists, then $h$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $\infty$ and also bounded in the complement of that neighborhood (which is a compact). Therefore, $h$ is entire and bounded. This implies it is constant.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Read edit above.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Yes, it does, actually. It is bounded for $|z|>N$ for some $N$, and it is bounded in the compact set $|z|\leq N$.